# List of a sealed class inside a sealed class| windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, background-task, sealed

I'm parsing JSON in a background task. I'm parsing the result to a class with the NewtonSoft parser.

[image: parsing]

Because the classes i'm parsing the result are sealed, it gives conflicts when i use a list of sealed class A in sealed class B

[image]

This gives me the errors

[image]

I'm fairly new to programming for windows phone and i have not a single clue what to do with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing `List<T>` to `IList<T>` as suggested by the compiler?

Comment: It looks like `List<T>` is not supported, it doesn't appear to be anything to do with the fact that the class is sealed.

Comment: apparently this solved the problem...
I didnt understand what the compiler was suggesting since i never really understood/understand what the I stands for. or what it actually does..
Thanks for the help !